# How is Reqwest higher level than Hyper?

Tags: rust, hyper, reqwest

According to the docs on Hyper.rs,

> If you are looking for a convenient HTTP client, then you may wish to consider `reqwest`. If you are looking for a convenient HTTP server, then you may wish to consider `warp`. Both are built on top of this library.

Looking at the api, it seems Hyper.rs is already pretty high level. It supports [proxies](https://docs.rs/hyper-proxy/0.8.0/hyper_proxy/), [tls](https://crates.io/crates/hyper-tls), and [cookies](https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/header/struct.HeaderName.html)... Why is Reqwest more high level?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hyper requires you to take care of lower level details, like parsing the URI (example from the [documentation](https://hyper.rs/guides/client/basic/)):

```
let client = Client::new();
let uri = "http://httpbin.org/ip".parse()?;
let mut resp = client.get(uri).await?;

while let Some(chunk) = resp.body_mut().data().await {
    stdout().write_all(&chunk?).await?;
}
```

while reqwest handle this for you (from [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.2/reqwest/#making-a-get-request)) :

```rust
let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
    .await?
    .text()
    .await?;
```